# Create a directed graph in openGL

Tags: opengl

I am trying to visualize a directed graph(in 2D plane) with openGL. I know how to do it for non-directed graphs using `GL_LINE` but I dont know how to create an arrow that begins frop point a and ends in point b. how can I write a function like `createArrow(Point a,Point b)` that do such thing ?

Comment: A line, then a triangle at the endpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To calculate the coordinates needed for drawing the arrow head lines/triangle, you can first calculate the normalized vector from the tip of the arrow to the base. If the line is from `(x1, y1)` to `(x2, y2)`, the direction vector is:

```
float vx = x1 - x2;
float vy = y1 - y2;
float s= 1.0f / sqrt(vx * vx + vy * vy);
vx *= s;
vy *= s;
```

To get a vector in a 45 degree angle from the tip, calculate the sum of this direction vector and a direction orthogonal to it. The two vectors orthogonal to `(vx, vy)` are:

```
(vy, -vx)
(-vy, vx)
```

Then the sums of the orthogonal vector and the direction vector are:

```
(vx, vy) + (vy, -vx) = (vx + vy, vy - vx)
(vx, vy) + (-vy, vx) = (vx - vy, vy + vx)
```

To get the coordinates of the arrow head points, add these vectors to the end point, scaled with the desired size of the tip. With a size `d` for the arrow tip, the 3 points of the arrow tip are:

```
(x2, y2)
(x2, y2) + d * (vx + vy, vy - vx)
(x2, y2) + d * (vx - vy, vy + vx)
```

For a filled arrow tip, draw a triangle with these 3 points. For a open tip, draw lines from the 1st to the 2nd and from the 1st to the 3rd point.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference in creating an arrow head would be two additional lines added onto the destination position vector. The heads need to be slightly rotated in opposite directions starting from the arrow's direction.

[image]

In my example I'm going to assume that the arrows are going to be static. This way I can do all calculations on the CPU, store the results in a vertex buffer object, and pass it on to the GPU. GPU will then render this VBO using `GL_LINES` property.

Here's some quick pseudo code that creates an arrow and stores the lines necessary to draw to it in a vector container.

```
void createArrow(vec2 source, vec2 destination, float headAngle, float headLength) {
    vec2 direction = normalize(destination - source);
    vec2 leftHead = destination - (rotate(direction, -headAngle) * headLength);
    vec2 rightHead = destination - (rotate(direction, headAngle) * headLength);

    vector<vec2> lines = {
        source,
        destination,

        destination,
        leftHead,

        destination,
        rightHead
    }

    // Generate new vertex buffer object, and fill it with data (lines).
}

//...

// Bind data and render it.
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 6);
```

To create a new arrow you would make this call, passing in your source and destination vectors. Then specify the angle by which to rotate your heads, and finally the length of the heads.

```
createArrow(playerPos, enemyPos, Math.PI/2.0f, 2.0f);
```

And again remember that this is just one way of doing it, there are many other ways. If you want to render arrows dynamically you could use the *Geometry Shader* which lets you generate extra lines(heads) on the fly, basically this way we can move most of the code from CPU to the GPU.

You could also render lines to a texture using a frame buffers and the fragment shader.